# Jboss local user can always modify standalone.xml in Windows?

Tags: windows, security, jakarta-ee, jboss

In Windows, I'm looking at JBoss security features, let's say you modified the standalone.xml and defined your security domains and everything is in place, what stops a user on the host where JBoss is running to modify your settings, restart JBoss and have access to everything in your applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, there is nothing to stop this.
Therefore, you need to:

- secure the data
- perhaps use version control mechanisms, so you can see what has changed, when it changed and who did it.

Similarly you will need to stop attackers (for example) deploying their own ear files to something untrustworthy